harvard cs109 HW0 goat_door
I need someone to help explain what is happening at the last line of the code in the given solution, especially how the part "result[bad]" works and why "bad.sum()" is needed as an argument
def goat_door(prizedoors, guesses):

#strategy: generate random answers, and
#keep updating until they satisfy the rule
#that they aren't a prizedoor or a guess
result = np.random.randint(0, 3, prizedoors.size)
while True:
    bad = (result == prizedoors) | (result == guesses)
    if not bad.any():
        return result
    result[bad] = np.random.randint(0, 3, bad.sum())

From what I understand, the last line is a way of replacing the bad and result variable with an empty array. I have improvised with my own code below but I still need to understand how the original solution works. Would appreciate any help thank you!
def goat_door(prizedoors, guesses):

result = np.random.randint(0,3, prizedoors.size)
while True:
    global choose_again
    choose_again = np.logical_or((result == prizedoors),(result == guesses))

    if not np.array(choose_again).any():
        return result
    choose_again = []
    result = np.random.randint(0,3, prizedoors.size)


Please include the code as text. Don't post code as images. It forces us to retype it all if we want to run it or make edits.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
